# 9-Rook problem in 3D / weak version of sudoku

Tags: combinatorics

So here I have a 9*9 grid, and I have to fill each row and each column with 1~9, but without the constraint about 3*3 boxes as in traditional sudoku. Suppose the grid is blank at first, in how many different ways can I fill the boxes?

Is there a (simple) mathematical way to compute this or do I have to write the DLX thingy? And is there a ready answer for this? Taking/not taking symmetry into account are both fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the 3x3 box constraints, this is just counting Latin squares ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatinSquare.html)).

The number of Latin squares of size $n\times n$ is sequence [A002860](http://oeis.org/A002860) in OEIS. See also [A000315](http://oeis.org/A000315).

The short answer is that there is no known formula, but the growth is so fast that you won't get far trying to count them by brute force however good your heuristic.

Comment: After seeing the sequence I have to say I'm glad that I posted the question here first instead of trying to write the code right off. I knew that an optimized algorithm can calculate 16-queen within 1 sec and I had expected that the answer to this Latin square problem would be less than 10^6 larger than n-queen. Clearly I'm wrong. Thanks!